# Writing a method for an array that returns true when every cell has an object/item and false when it does not (an empty/NULL cell)

Tags: java, methods

This is what I have, but it's wrong. Am I missing a key idea or is it a silly mistake?

```
private boolean[] isFull(){
 if (boolean[] == true || false){
    return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to loop through the array first, check each cell for empty

Comment: That's not close to legal Java syntax. You should be getting error messages when you compile. Follow those to start with.

Comment: Where's your array?

Answer (score 0):

The statement `boolean[] == true` is syntactically incorrect. You need to specify a variable for an if statement like that. Something like :

```
boolean myVar;
...

...

if (myVar == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to find out if an array has no nulls.

Here is a method using a loop:

```
private boolean isFull(Type array[]) {
    for (Type value: array) {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or using streams:

```
return Arrays.stream(array).noneMatch(Objects::isNull);
```